# Making changes to my program after updating my database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Sorry if my question is not specific or if it has been answered before. I tried looking for it and for a better way to ask but this is the most accurate way.

I have developed a program in Java in which I insert a new row into my database in the following way:

`INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?,?,?)`

The thing is that I have this query in many parts of the program, and now I decided to add a fourth column to my table. Do I have to update EVERY SINGLE query with a new question mark in the program? If I dont, it crashes.

What is the best way to proceed in these cases?

Comment: Simple answer - Yes.  Longer answer, isolate the code into as few locations as possible, create a static method if you REALLY have to, preferably, use inheritance if possible.  The intention of OO is to reduce this kind of problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES.

you need to add extra `?` (*parameter placeholder*) because you are using `implicit` `INSERT` statement. That means that you didn't specify the column names of the table to which the values will be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?,?,?)
// the server assumes that you are inserting values for all
// columns in your table
// if you fail to add value on one column. an exception will be thrown
```

The next time you create an `INSERT` statement, make sure that you specify the column names on it so when you alter the table by adding extra column, you won't update all your place holders.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (Col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?)
// the server knows that you are inserting values for a specific column
```

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to update EVERY SINGLE query with a new question mark in the program?

Probably. What you should do, while you're updating every single one of those queries, is to encapsulate them into an object, probably using a Data Source pattern such as a [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) or a [Row Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html). That way you [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and the next time you update the table, you only have one place to update the query.

Comment: Thank you for the pattern recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the syntax you've used, you might run some issues. I've referring to the lack of column names. Your `INSERT` queries will start failing as soon as you change your table structure.

If you had used the following syntax:
`INSERT INTO table_name (C1, C2, C3) VALUES (?,?,?)`
assuming your new column has a proper default value, then it would've work fine.